# Why was yellow bile/choler believed to cause anger?

Tags: physiology

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/choleric), "choleric" derives from from Greek kholera "a type of disease characterized by diarrhea, supposedly caused by bile" with bile being "khole", so called for its color, greenish-yellow. From 1580s comes the meaning of "easily angered, hot-tempered" and "pertaining to cholera" from 1834. But why was yellow bile associated with anger?

Answer (score 2):

We do not really know. The association comes from ancient medicine of humors, black bile, yellow bile, phlegm, and blood, four supposed bodily fluids. Considering that "phlegm" does not exist and black and yellow bile are the same substance in modern view it is hard to say why semi-fictional "fluids" were associated with observed phenomena, perhaps they were postulated just for the purpose of explaining them. Indeed, it is not the fluid associations that were the rational kernel of humoric explanations, but rather the interrelations between various ailments that they were used to express.

The doctrine of four humors can be traced back to Ancient Egypt and Mesopotamia, but it took its classical form in Greece around 400 BC and was canonized by Hippocrates of Kos. Greeks associated the four humors to four elements (earth, water, air and fire). In Roman times Galen (129–201 AD) further related them to  four temperaments (melancholic, phlegmatic, sanguinic and choleric). The yellow bile was associated with fire, which explains its later relation to the "fiery" choleric temperament, and, in excess, to anger, see [Wikipedia's History of Humorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humorism).

A Swedish physician Fahraeus speculated that the idea of humors came from observing blood clotting. His speculation would explain why the lightest "fluid" (yellow bile) was associated with the lightest element (fire), but it is not entirely convincing. Here is from [Hart's Descriptions of Blood and Blood Disorders before the Advent of Laboratory Studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11843802):

> "*Fahraeus  (1921),  a  Swedish  physician  who  devised  the erythrocyte   sedimentation   rate,   suggested   that   the   four humours were based upon the observation of blood clotting in  a  transparent  container.  Following  the  clotting  of  the homogeneous  red  fluid,  it  separates  into  a  dark  red/black clot  at  the  bottom  with  a  thin  layer  of  red  cells  above  it. Above this is a pale green or whitish layer and the contents are  surrounded  by  clear   yellow  serum.  Certainly,  clotted blood reveals the humours of blood and yellow bile, but the appearance  of  black  bile  and  phlegm  is  not  so  apparent.*"